# Train YOLO with height = 320 and width = 320

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I am training my object detection model with two classes using YOLOV3. In the config file of yolov3.cfg its default **height = 416 and width = 416**. Now I want to train it with **height = 320 and width = 320** so I made these changes and started my training but this is giving me average loss = Nan. But when I train it with 416 x 416 it works completely fine.

So how can I train my model with 320 x 320 instead of 416 x 416.

Answer (score 0):

So YOLOV3 has a default height and weight of 416. So to get 320 I have changed it in the .tflite model instead of .cfg.